# For an e-commerce website, how many pages should I allow users to navigate through?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, ecommerce, pagination

some e-commerce website do not allow user to go through high page numbers, for example:

**Gumtree** allows max 50 pages

Note that there are 163K produces in the search result (no filter was used) and page size is 24, but use can go through the first 50 pages.

[image]

[image]

On the other had some e-commerce website allow user to go through all pages, for example:

---

**Kijiji** allows user to go through all 111307 pages

[image]

---

Elasticsearch by default allows pagination through 10K records, obviously this number can be changed but there are performance implications.

**Questions**

1. What is the best practice from SEO's point of view? I tried finding a document with some recommendations but I could not find anything.
2. If I follow Gumtree's example and limit the pagination to 50 Pages, would Google still index all of my products?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the the best practice from an SEO POV, if you have 1000's [or more] pages, google is unlikely to index them all -  Google will likely not index all the pages it knows about.  (This is a wide topic which is a little beyond my expertise, but research the term "Crawl Budget" to learn more about this)

You should have the pages you want indexed in a sitemap that you give to Google, and not rely Google crawling your site.

I doubt Google cares that much about how many page results you return to users - I expect that limiting this is a pragmatic decision dependent on server resources and limiting [undesirable] bot hits / gathering of competitive intelligence.